# JavaScript extending Array to implement map2

Tags: javascript

I want extend javascript  Array to implement map2 functionality without using inbuilt map function. Where map2 functionality doubles the passed value of the array.

For example:

```
var m = [1,2,3,4,5]
var double = [1,2,3,4,5].map2(doubleFn)
console.log(double) should output 2,4,6,8,10
```

And above functionality need be developed by **without** using any in built method of JS array

**Code Snippet**

```
 Array.prototype.map2= function(callback, thisArg){
      var len=this.length
      for(var i in this){
        callback.call(this,this[i]*2)
      } 
   }
```

Please let me know, what approach can I follow to do this

Comment: @AnuragPeshne, as i mentioned in the question, I cannot use in built map of array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.map2 = function (callback, thisArg){
  var i, el,
      len   = this.length,
      res   = [],
      _this = thisArg ? thisArg : this;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    el     = this[i];  // also you can use this[i] * 2 - it depend what do want; 
    res[i] = callback.call(_this, el);    
  }

  return res;
};

var double = [1,2,3,4,5].map2(function (el) {
  return el * 2;
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/fixaba/1/edit?js,console)

About you errors, don't use `for..in` for Arrays., in `map` you need create new array and return it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want to re implement built in `Array.prototype.map`.
Here's one of the way of doing it:

```
Array.prototype.map2 = function(f1){
  var a = [];
  this.forEach(function(element){
    a.push(f1(element));
  })
  return a;
}

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(a.map2(function(a){return a<<1;});
//output: [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
```

**Edit**: without using inbuilt functions:

```
Array.prototype.map2 = function(f1){
  var a = [];
  var that = this;
  return (function recArray(index, target){
    if(typeof(that[index]) !== 'undefined') {
      target[index] = f1(that[index]);
      return recArray(index + 1, target);
    }
    return target;
  })(0, a);
}
```

**But there is a problem with this solution:**

What if input Array has holes:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[12] = 11
//now a is: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, , , , , , , , 11 ]
```

JavaScript Arrays can have holes and if there are `undefined` values in between then above method will fail. Without knowing the length of the Array, it is impossible to traverse it if it contains 'holes'.

Explicitly storing length doesn't makes sense as it is stored in `Array.prototype.length`.
Hence if the array is not contiguous then without using length it is impossible to implement `map`.

Comment: Thanks, But you are using foEach and push methods which are inbuilt method. it need to done without using inbuilt methods of array

Comment: @niran this recursive version doesn't use any in built functions. I hope you are fine with `typeof` operator.